# When the temperature in a building is already "freezing", does it matter how "freezing" it is?

Tags: frostpunk

In the later phases of the game's campaign, it is possible for buildings to get so cold that even if you take efforts to get them warmer (heaters, steam conduits...) they are still marked as "freezing".

Is there a point in taking these efforts to make such buildings "not *that* far below the freezing point", or is "freezing" always as bad as it gets?

Answer (score 2):

[From the wiki](https://frostpunk.gamepedia.com/Heat) (edited for brevity):

```
Temperature Level           Diff  Effect on Health
Comfortable (0°C +)         +2    Cannot become ill
Livable (-1°C to -10°C)     +1    Very low risk of becoming ill
Chilly (-10°C to -20°C)      0    Low risk of becoming ill
Cold (-20°C to -30°C)       -1    Moderate risk of becoming ill
Very Cold (-30°C to -40°C)  -2    High risk of becoming ill (...)
Freezing (-50°C or lower)   -3    Very high risk of becoming ill (...)
```

The games marks something as **Freezing** once it reaches a temperature of -50°C or lower. Anything below this, is still **Freezing**, and subject to the same effects. Essentially, the game works with Heat Level Differentials, ranging from +2 to -3, where -3 is the worst it can get (Freezing).

So to answer your question: **no, it does not make a difference** if you make your buildings not *that* far below freezing point. You will want to reach the previous level of Heat Differential (-2, or warmer than -40°C) to get any change in effects.

Comment: Is there a typo here, or does the game actually have some kind of "limbo state" between -40 and -50?  Does the building stay "Very Cold" until it hits -50 on the way down, but then stay "Freezing" until it hits -40 on the way up?

Comment: @Steve-O That wiki table indeed seems to be a bit weird. The game always sets the temperature to exact multiples of 10.